# TypeError: Factory.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, typeerror

I am writing my first angular application with a web api and I am having some problems with calling functions from a factory.

I have two factories that looks like this:

```
main.factory('Table', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        build: function (token, cubeid) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:50051/api/structure/cube',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                transformRequest: function (obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for (var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: { token: token, cubeId: cubeid }
            });
        }
    };
});

main.factory('Login', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        authorize: function (username, password) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'path/to/api/',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                transformRequest: function (obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for (var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: { username: username, password: password }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And two controllers that looks like this:

```
main.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$location', 'Login', function jobListController($scope, $log, $http, $location, Login) {

    $scope.login = function () {
        Login.authorize($scope.username, $scope.password).success(function (response) {
            $location.path('/table/'+response.token);
        });
    }

}]);

main.controller('tableController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$log', '$http', 'Table', function tableController($scope, $routeParams, $log, Table) {
    var cube = 130;
    var token = $routeParams.token;
    $log.log($routeParams.token);
    Table.build(token, cube).success(function (response) {
        $scope.structure = response;
        $log.log(response);
    });
}]);
```

For some reason the build function raises an error saying "TypeError: Table.build is not a function" while the authorize function works like a charm.

Can anyone explain to me why the build function does not work?

PS: I have checked that the token actually gets passet through to the controller.

Comment: Are you referring to the buildtable function? Because this is called plain "build" in your Table factory

Comment: Sorry, it should have been build both places. That was not the issue, it still does not work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you inject different services/factories to your controller

```
['$scope', '$routeParams', '$log', '$http', 'Table', 
function tableController($scope, $routeParams, $log, Table)
```

should be

```
['$scope', '$routeParams', '$log', '$http', 'Table', 
function tableController($scope, $routeParams, $log, $http, Table)
```